# Related PDFs of Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

The continuous random variable $T$ has probability density function given by

$$f_T(t)= 
\begin{cases}
0 & t <2, \\
\frac{2}{(t-1)^3} & t \ge 2.
\end{cases}$$

Find the probability density function of $Y$, where $Y = \frac{1}{T-1}$.

I understand that I need to look at cumulative probability functions, but the answer seems not to be normalised, as I think my problem lies with dealing with the constraints on $t$.